# fd_set not recognized in Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm working in Eclipse on an assignment involving a server and clients communicating via sockets. I'm trying to use the `accept` system call, which uses the `fd_set` struct. The problem is Eclipse indicates that the type `fd_set` is unresolved.

Here is a list of my imports:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Why is Eclipse indicating *fd_set is not recognized*?

Answer (score 6):

According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set, `#include <sys/select.h>`. Hopefully that will do the trick.

Comment: Also see [The Open Group Base Specification, sys/select.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/sys/select.h.html). Its effectively where Posix states to find `fd_set`.